# Maven deploy .jar to network location

Tags: maven, jar

How can I deploy a .jar to a network path?  I'm looking at [maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) and other examples and keep finding things about deploying to tomcat, glassfish and ftp.  My needs are simpler.  I only need to deploy to a network path.

Bonus: After running a network path, is it possible to run console commands on an external windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

The maven-deploy-plugin is intended to deploy an artifact to a repository which means usually to a repository manager (Artifactory, Nexus, Archiva etc.). The things you are talking about can be handled by the [tomcat6- or tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/) which support the things you need. Other containers like Glassfish can be handled by [cargo2-maven-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin). I'm not aware of a up-to-date glassfish-maven-plugin only this one [maven-glassfish-plugin](https://maven-glassfish-plugin.java.net/) which looks out of date ([Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836317/which-maven-glassfish-plugin-to-use)).

If you like making deployments via ftp you can use the following configuration for the [maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>ftp-repository</id>
      <url>ftp://repository.mycompany.com/repository</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
         <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>
  ...
</project>

<settings>
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ftp-repository</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>pass</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

But this is in contradiction to the idea of Maven.

You can try to use the deploy-file goal of the maven-deploy-plugin to see if this would be option to deploy to a network path. I'm not sure if this will work.